# Text font does not set?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to set the font type for my label text but it does not seted .....

my code....

```
CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 80);
    labelResizableView = [[UserResizableView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
    alabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 35, 100, 100)];

alabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter-Bold" size:18];
```

Comment: Is `AmericanTypewriter-Bold` a supported font on iOS? Have you looked with `NSLog(@"Fonts: %@", [UIFont familyNames]);`?

Comment: @jjv360 http://iosfonts.com/

Comment: yes it is supported,ios5

Comment: @lipid give the space between "American Typewriter" mate, see my bellow answer..

Comment: @trojanfoe O I see, that's quite a useful site there I didn't know about...

Comment: actually,problem is that i am setting font size after this code so thats why this code does not work.

Comment: how can i set only font style not size?

Comment: @lipid Get the current size first: `CGFloat size = alabel.font.pointSize`.

Comment: @lipid And then use the size returned when creating the new font.

Comment: There is not any problem with your code to set label font and size alabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter-Bold" size:18]; It's working fine. As **jjv360** said you just check that this font is available at your end or not. NSLog(@"Fonts: %@", [UIFont familyNames]);

Comment: what are you displaying in your label..

Answer (score 0):

use this code mate..

```
  [alabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"American Typewriter-Bold" size:18]];
```

Comment: How is that different from the OP's code, apart from not using Objective-C-2.0-style assignments?  Oh, and an incorrectly spelt font name...

Comment: @trojanfoe yes mate exact so i just post with whole line of code right mate??

Comment: What are you talking about mate?

Comment: i just talking about font name with incorrect mate so i just correct it

Comment: oh ok ok sir.. now its ok??